# PHP Can't upload large video to the SQL database

Tags: php, upload, filesize, video-upload

I am trying to upload videos to a database using PHP and MySQL. I can upload small video files to the website and database but when I use a medium to large file sizes it comes up with errors. I have tried changing php.ini file but still have same problem. Is there problem with my upload form code? I can manually add large file through phpmyadmin but not through the form.

```
<?php
    require('inc/connection.php');
    require('inc/function.php');

    //ToDo header title
     $header = "Upload";
    require('inc/header.php');


    if(isset($_GET['status'])){
    $header = "successed";
    if($_GET['status']=='uploaded'){
        echo '<br><br><br><br>';
        echo '<h1><center> :) </h1>';
        echo '<p><center>Your Video upload is successful.</p>';
        die();
        }
     }

    //header title
    $header = "Upload";

    //if not Loggedin redirect to the main page
    if(!loggedin() || checkAdmin()){
    header('Location: index.php');
    }
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    
    //Filtering input
    $title = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"title",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $description = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST,"description",FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
    
    //Files to be uploaded
    $vid_tmp_name = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];
    $thumbn_tmp_name = $_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'];
    
    //Check if empty (required fields)
    if(empty($title) || empty($vid_tmp_name)|| empty($thumbn_tmp_name) ){
            $error_message[] = "Please fill in the required fields: Title, 
    Video and Thumbnail.";
    }
    if(empty($description)){
        $description = "(NULL)";
    }
    if(strlen($title)>70){
        $error_message[] = " Title must be less than 70 character.";
    }
        
    if(!isset($error_message)){
        loader("Please Wait .. ");
        //date of the video
        $t=time();
        $date=date("M d, Y",$t);
        
        //name of the video & thumbnail
        $d = date_create();
        $name = date_timestamp_get($d);
        
        if (!is_dir('./media/video/')) {
            mkdir('./media/video/', 0755, true);         
        }
        if (!is_dir('./media/thumbnail/')) {
            mkdir('./media/thumbnail/', 0755, true);         
        }
        
        try{
            //Full direction of both video & thumbnail
            $vid_uploads_dir = './media/video/'.$name.'.mp4';
            $thumbn_uploads_dir = './media/thumbnail/'.$name.'.jpg';
            
            //Start uploading
            move_uploaded_file($vid_tmp_name, $vid_uploads_dir);
            move_uploaded_file($thumbn_tmp_name, $thumbn_uploads_dir);
            //Add video metadata to the DB
            addVideoRequest($title, $description, $_SESSION['id'], $name, 
    $name, $date);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $error_message[] = "Error : ".$e->getMessage();
        }
       }
      if(isset($error_message)){
    echo '<div class="wrapper"><div 
     class="error">'.$error_message[0].'</div></div>';
      }else if(is_file($vid_uploads_dir) && is_file($thumbn_uploads_dir) ){
        //if the uploaded do exist then
        //Redirect to this page
        header('refresh:1;url=upload.php?status=uploaded');
        //header('Location: upload.php?status=uploaded');
    }else{
        $error_message[] = "Error occurred, Please try again !!";
       }
    }
    ?>

        <div class="wrapper content">
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Title *</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="title"  maxlength="70"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Video *</th>
                <td><input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Thumbnail *</th>
                <td><input type="file" name="thumbnail" accept="image/*"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description" maxlength="250"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Upload"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<?php require('inc/footer.php');?>
```

I have tried changing the database structure and changing php.ini

I have changed values below for php.ini

```
memory_limit=1200M
post_max_size=8000M
upload_max_filesize=2000M
```

The error code I get for the large file is:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 73666615 bytes exceeds the limit of 68157440 bytes in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Undefined index: video in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registration\upload.php on line 35
>
> Notice: Undefined index: thumbnail in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registration\upload.php on line 36

The small video files are successful but still confused about what is happening

the actual result should able to upload the video successful for large video files.

Comment: I see no SQL here.